# Como carregar dinamicamente staticfiles CSS e Javascripts em Django

Tags: python, css, django

Estou escrevendo em Python com Django. Como prática comum, criei um template "base.html" que depois vai ser estendido por várias outras páginas. Cada uma vai ter o seu ficheiro CSS e o seu próprio ficheiro Javascript, portanto, embora sejam ficheiros "estáticos", eles são carregados dinamicamente conforme o doc HTML.
Encontrei duas soluções que ambas funcionam mas não sei se alguma delas dará problemas mais tarde.
1ª solução: Definir um bloco para as linhas com as tags de link e script; assim:
base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
  <head>
...
{% block 'estilos' %}{% endblock %}
{% block 'scripts' %}{% endblock %}
...
```

file.html:

```
{% load static %}
{% block 'estilos' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'nome_da_app/style.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
{% block 'scripts' %}
<script src="{% static 'nome_da_app/javascript.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

A 2ª solução, levou-me a criar um bloco apenas no sítio onde carrego o ficheiro, e é a forma que adotei e estou atualmente a utilizar:

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% block 'estilos' %}{% endblock %}">
      <script src="{% block 'scripts' %}{% endblock %}"></script>
  </head>
```

file.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block 'estilos' %}
{% static 'nome_da_app/style.css' %}
{% endblock %}
{% block 'scripts' %}
{% static 'nome_da_app/javascript.js' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Esta última solução tem um handicap que só agora a expor a questão é que me apercebi: é que só permite o carregamento de um e apenas um ficheiro de estilos e Javascript.
Mas em termos de funcionalidade, penso que ambas funcionarão corretamente?
Já agora aproveito para expor mais um problema que estava tendo: as alterações de CSS que eu ia fazendo não se refletiam e quando abria o editor de estilos das ferramentas de programador web do meu Firefox, nem as regras que lá estavam eram as atuais. "Vi-me grego" até conseguir resolver o problema!
SOLUÇÃO: Nas mesmas ferramentas de programador web, separador "Rede", há uma caixa de seleção de nome "Desativar cache" que ao ativar me resolveu o problema.

PS: É a minha primeira publicação, desculpem-me se estará um pouco atabalhoada, mas melhorarei no futuro.

Cumprimentos e saúde a todos!
Johnny

Answer (score 0):

Tente assim:

base.html

```
{% block scripts %}
<script src="caminho_1/script.js"></script>
...
<script src="caminho_N/script.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Deixa no base os que precisam estar em todas as páginas, e os adicionais pra páginas especificas, chama o bloco e adiciona nela mesmo, tipo:

template_qualquer.html

```
{% block scripts %}
<script src="caminho_extra_do_template/script.js"></script>
...
<script src="caminho_extra_do_template_N/script.js"></script>
{% endblock %}
```